# Why predictions are non-linear in logistic regression and are they interactions?

Tags: r, logistic, predictive-models, interaction

Consider this logistic regression on the `Titanic` dataset, with two predictors (one factor, `Pclass` and one continuous, `Age`):

```r
library(modelr)
library(titanic)
library(tidyverse)

titanic <- titanic::titanic_train
m <- glm(Survived ~ factor(Pclass) + Age, data = titanic, family = "binomial")
summary(m)

# Call:
#   glm(formula = Survived ~ factor(Pclass) + Age, family = "binomial",
#       data = titanic)
# 
# Deviance Residuals:
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
# -2.1524  -0.8466  -0.6083   1.0031   2.3929
# 
# Coefficients:
#                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#   (Intercept)      2.296012   0.317629   7.229 4.88e-13 ***
#   factor(Pclass)2 -1.137533   0.237578  -4.788 1.68e-06 ***
#   factor(Pclass)3 -2.469561   0.240182 -10.282  < 2e-16 ***
#   Age             -0.041755   0.006736  -6.198 5.70e-10 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
# Null deviance: 964.52  on 713  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 827.16  on 710  degrees of freedom
# (177 observations deleted due to missingness)
# AIC: 835.16
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

We have no interaction term, yet when we plot the predicted probability of surviving, we get non-parallel lines between the different classes:

```r
grid <- data_grid(titanic, Pclass = factor(Pclass), Age = seq_range(Age, 10))
survived <- predict(m, grid, type = "response")
grid <- cbind(grid, survived)

ggplot(grid, aes(Age, survived, color = Pclass)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

I assume this is because we are doing a logistic regression.

Still, I wonder if we can interpret that as interactions, e.g. here that for older passengers, the class matters less than for younger passengers?

Comment: These lines are parallel when you apply the logistic link function.  Doing so might make it easier to study interactions visually.

Comment: Indeed, the predictions we get from logit are inherently nonlinear, see e.g. https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/11.2-palr.html